# Custom defined type for cv::Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to create an array using cv::Mat with my custom defined type. Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
  int x;
  int y;
  float prob;
}CellXY;

void main(){

  cv::Mat_<CellXY> map(10, 10);

  std::cout << "Width = " << map.cols << ", Height = " << map.rows << std::endl;
  std::cout << "### Assignment ###" << std::endl;
  for (int j=0; j<map.rows; j++){
    for (int i=0; i<map.cols; i++){
      map.at<CellXY>(j, i).x = i;
      map.at<CellXY>(j, i).y = j;
      map.at<CellXY>(j, i).prob = (float)(i + j * map.cols);

      std::cout << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).prob 
        << " (" << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).x
        << "," << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).y
        << ")\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "### Display ###" << std::endl;
  for (int j=0; j<map.rows; j++){
    for (int i=0; i<map.cols; i++){
      std::cout << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).prob 
        << " (" << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).x
        << "," << map.at<CellXY>(j, i).y
        << ")\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 
  }
  map.release();
}
```

However results between "Assignment" and "Display" sections are not the same:

[image]

How do I make these results the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is becasue OpenCV doesn't know the `DataType` of your class. You need to a specialization for it, something like:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    float prob;
}CellXY;


// Add this!!!!!!
namespace cv {
template<> class DataType<CellXY>
{
public:
    typedef CellXY      value_type;
    typedef value_type  work_type;
    typedef value_type  channel_type;
    typedef value_type  vec_type;
    enum { generic_type = 0,
        depth        = CV_32F, // Might cause problems... I'm saying it's all made of floats (and not 2 int a 1 float)
        channels     = 3,
        fmt          = (int)'p',
        type         = CV_MAKETYPE(depth, channels)
    };
};
}

void main() {
    ...
}
```

But, in general, I think it's better to avoid messing up with these implementation details, and just use a better data structure. The recommendation is: **use `Mat` only for primitive types**. In fact, you can't use it in other OpenCV functions anyway...

Here a few ways to solve your problem:

1. Use another data structure: e.g. a `std::vector<std::vector<CellXY>>` or an *"unrolled"* `std::vector<CellXY>`
2. Make a class `CellXYMatrix` which deals with storing the `CellXY`:

   ```
   class CellXYMatrix
   {
        std::vector<CellXY> _mat; // your matrix of CellXY
        int _r; // rows
        int _c; // cols

   public:
        CellXYMatrix(int rows, int cols) : _r(rows), _c(cols), _mat(rows * cols) {};

        void set(int row, int col, const CellXY& cell) {
           _mat[row * _c + col] = cell;
        }
        CellXY& get(int row, int col) {
           return _mat[row * _c + col];
        }  
   }
   ```

   You can eventually overload `operator()` to make the access similar to OpenCV Mats.
3. If the `x` and `y` fields in `CellXY` refer to the matrix position, why do you need them? You can simply have a `Mat1f` (aka `Mat_<float>`) for your probabilities, and x,y are the position in the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried your solution by adding template<> class DataType<CellXY> but I got this error:

error: specialization of ‘template<class _Tp> class cv::DataType’ in different namespace [-fpermissive] template<> class DataType<CellXY>

However, I do agree that using cv::Mat for primitive types such as cv::Point3f or cv::Vec3f is always better.

FYI: Additionally I tried to modify the data type in the "CellXY" structure as shown below, and it works perfectly without adding template DataType class.

typedef struct{
  float x;
  float y;
  float prob;
}CellXY;

Comment: 1) You need to put the specialization into the `namespace cv`... see edit. 2) Oh, didn't know that... but then you can just use `cv::Vec3f`;)

Comment: The reason I want to use cv::Mat, instead of std::vector because I want to dynamically change the size of 2D array. In OpenCV, it can be done easily with cv::hconcat(B, A, result) or cv::vconcat(B, A, result). So, the new array can be added to the original array at either top, bottom, left, or right position with ease.

Comment: It would be trivial to add that to the `CellXYMatrix` class. But, as long you're 100% sure that OpenCV functions works well with your custom data type, I guess you're safe ;)

Comment: @puwanan BTW, great 1st question ;)