# How to make cv::Mat_ objects

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-mat

I need to use class cv::Mat_ from OpenCV library for performing some data processing.

I have a struct type such as this

```
struct data{short a; short b; short c; }
```

If I try to create a cv::Mat_ object like this,

```
cv::Mat_<data>d_cells(10,50);
```

I get an error in Visual Studio,

> 'channel_type': is not a member of 'cv::DataType<_Tp>'

I've tried reading documentation and reading other posts regarding the same error, but it didn't solve my problem. I am new to c++.

Could someone help me?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089181/custom-defined-type-for-cvmat-in-opencv

Comment: FYI, your `struct data` is equivalent to `cv::CV_16SC3`, which is a member of `cv::DataType`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It helped me resolve my issue.